# Related objects or default

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Is there a simple way to query a reverse relation filtering on a value which is the default if the object does not yet exists?

Let me elaborate more with an example.

I have the following basic models models:

```
class Delegation(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=4)
    country = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

class Exam(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now I need to store the information about some action, basically if the action is still in progress or finalized (submitted). For this reason I use a model that link to both models.

```
class ExamAction(models.Model):
    OPEN = 'O'
    SUBMITTED = 'S'
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((OPEN, 'In progress'), (SUBMITTED, 'Submitted'))
    TRANSLATION = 'T'
    POINTS = 'P'
    ACTION_CHOICES = ((TRANSLATION, 'Translation submission'), (POINTS, 'Points submission'))
    exam       = models.ForeignKey(Exam)
    delegation = models.ForeignKey(Delegation)
    action     = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
    status     = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=OPEN)
    timestamp  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('exam', 'delegation', 'action'),)
```

My problem is that queries get now pretty complex, because (for the moment) I assume that the action could not yet be listed in the DB, for which I would assume the default value of `ExamAction.OPEN`.

For a concrete example, this is what I use at the moment to query the list of exams that are still open for a delegation:

```
exams_open = Exam.objects.filter((Q(examaction__delegation=delegation) & Q(examaction__action=ExamAction.TRANSLATION) & Q(examaction__status=ExamAction.OPEN))
     | Q(examaction__isnull=True), active=True, )
```

I believe the above query is also wrong, because it should return an `Exam` object if there is no `ExamAction` with `action=TRANSLATION` and `delegation=delegation`, but it won't if another action is already stored (with whatever value).

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one encountering this design problem and I think that a much easier implementation must exist. But what?

What I'm currently considering is:

1. `ExamAction.objects.get_or_create()`

   - Problem 1: this does not work on multiple matches, i.e. the get query should be unique
   - Problem 2: it is not nice to *create* objects in a GET request.
2. Generate all possible `ExamAction` when I create new `Exam` object. This would imply looping though all delegations.

   - What if a delegation is added after the exam is generated?
3. Does a ManyToMany relationship with `through=ExamAction` help in this situation? I don't think so, because I should still query for ExamAction having the desired (default) value or non-existing yet.
4. A complete redesign? I'm open to possible ideas!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired query correctly, I would put it like this (here as a custom method on a `Manager`):

```
# UPDATE: Bugfix thanks to Mic D.
class ExamManager(models.Manager):
    def open_exams(delegation, action):
        return Exam.objects.exclude(
            examaction__in=ExamAction.objects.filter(
                delegation=delegation, 
                action=action,
                status=ExamAction.SUBMITTED,
            )
        ).distinct()
```

So that's not too bad.

Looking briefly at your proposed solutions:

1. As you note this only operates on one row at a time.
2. For most such questions this is what  I'd suggest. But in your case it would quadratically increase the size of your database, and it would make life more complicated when you add a new delegation.
3. A `ManyToManyField` is just some syntactic sugar, it wouldn't do anything for you here.
4. This could be a good idea, but there's not enough information here to really make any suggestions.

So I think your approach is actually pretty reasonable, and you just need to figure out the right queries.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The query in the Manager is indeed much more elegant and it is not so ugly to maintain as I though in the beginning.

Comment: I tried out to pursue a bit point 2. Since eventually I will end up having the large quadratic database, I can just create all the entries in the beginning, and to avoid creation on GET requests, I used the post_save signals on both Delegation and Exam.

Comment: Note that I found a problem in the query that you proposed. I posted how I fixed and some verbose debugging.

Comment: @MicD: Thanks for the clarification. I was surprised by your results because that's the opposite of what would happen with `filter()`. But I see that this exact point (on the difference between `filter()` and `exclude()` when it comes to spanning multi-valued relationships) is [noted in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships). I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The query that I ended up using is:

```
exams_open = Exam.objects.exclude(
    examaction__in=ExamAction.objects.filter(
        delegation=delegation,
        action=ExamAction.TRANSLATION,
        status=ExamAction.SUBMITTED)
).distinct()
```

This was inspired by [Kevin Christopher Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058523/4825266), however I found a bug in it. To debug it I actually had to print the generated query with `print QuerySet.query`. The difference is quite subtle, but in my case it made a huge difference.

**Wrong query:**

```
print Exam.objects.exclude(
            examaction__delegation=delegation, 
            examaction__action=action,
            examaction__status=ExamAction.SUBMITTED,
        ).query
```

Output:

```
SELECT "app_exam"."id",
       "app_exam"."name"
FROM   "app_exam"
WHERE  NOT ( "app_exam"."id" IN (SELECT U1."exam_id" AS Col1
                                 FROM   "app_examaction" U1
                                 WHERE  U1."action" = t)
             AND "app_exam"."id" IN (SELECT U1."exam_id" AS Col1
                                     FROM   "app_examaction" U1
                                     WHERE  U1."delegation_id" = 1)
             AND "app_exam"."id" IN (SELECT U1."exam_id" AS Col1
                                     FROM   "app_examaction" U1
                                     WHERE  U1."status" = s) )
```

Here any exam which meets any of the `exclude()` statements gets removed.

For the **correct query**:

```
print Exam.objects.exclude(
    examaction__in=ExamAction.objects.filter(
        delegation=delegation,
        action=ExamAction.TRANSLATION,
        status=ExamAction.SUBMITTED)
).query
```

Output:

```
SELECT "app_exam"."id",
       "app_exam"."name"
FROM   "app_exam"
WHERE  NOT ( "app_exam"."id" IN (SELECT V1."exam_id" AS Col1
                                 FROM   "app_examaction" V1
                                 WHERE  V1."id" IN (SELECT U0."id"
                                                    FROM   "app_examaction" U0
                                                    WHERE  ( U0."delegation_id"
                                                             = 1
                                                             AND U0."action" = t
                                                             AND U0."status" = s
                                                           ))) )
```

Here we correctly exclude the exams only once.